# Scale Android drawable to fill whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout

There is an an image set as a background for activity. I would like to scale an image so that it always fills the whole screen like in the example without excessive scaling. How to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: have you tried scaleType:centercrop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/nSx3W"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

[image: Result]